# Transform a xml response with wiremock

Tags: wiremock

I would like to change the value of a xml element dynamically to return as a response using wiremock. This value has to be calculated according to some project rules at runtime. It is not something I can read from the request or some fixed value. How can I achieve that using wiremock?

I was reading about transforming responses here https://wiremock.org/docs/extensibility/transforming-responses/ but I cannot find the dependency from where I should import the class ResponseDefinitionTransformerV2.

The only wiremock dependency I have on the project is this

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.wiremock</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Should I have another?

If I write my own transformer, how to I deploy it into the docker container? Since I am running wire mock from a docker container.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my on question:

- create a separate jar project with the transformer as an extension
- put the jar in the docker container in the extensions folder
- configure the --extensions value in the docker command line with the full class name of the transformer
- use the transformer in the json configuration

Comment: Worth adding that the --extensions bit is no longer necessary if you include a service descriptor file under META-INF in the extension JAR.